# Using own maptile for googlemaps API

Tags: javascript, html, api

i have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Image map types</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
var moonTypeOptions = {
  getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
      var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
      if (!normalizedCoord) {
        return null;
      }
      var bound = Math.pow(2, zoom);
      return 'http://mw1.google.com/mw-planetary/lunar/lunarmaps_v1/clem_bw' +
          '/' + zoom + '/' + normalizedCoord.x + '/' +
          (bound - normalizedCoord.y - 1) + '.jpg';
  },
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
  maxZoom: 9,
  minZoom: 0,
  radius: 1738000,
  name: 'Moon'
};

var moonMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(moonTypeOptions);

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatlng,
    zoom: 1,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ['moon']
    }
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
  map.mapTypes.set('moon', moonMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('moon');
}

// Normalizes the coords that tiles repeat across the x axis (horizontally)
// like the standard Google map tiles.
function getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom) {
  var y = coord.y;
  var x = coord.x;

  // tile range in one direction range is dependent on zoom level
  // 0 = 1 tile, 1 = 2 tiles, 2 = 4 tiles, 3 = 8 tiles, etc
  var tileRange = 1 << zoom;

  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to change the background image to my own but everytime i change the path it stops working.

can someone tell me how i change the path correctly to /Users/Chris/Pictures/test1.jpg ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the georeferenced tiles in Mercator system and provide link to these.

The easiest step-by-step tutorial how to do that for a JPEG image you have on your hard disk is visible in this video:

[image: Map overlay step-by-step]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJxdCe9CNYg

It is using http://www.maptiler.com/ utility, which generates a sample googlemaps.html viewer for you.

You can create the tiles also with open-source software - such as my GDAL2Tiles utility, or with your own software by applying the math described at: http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/